# ObjectBox, sum a property by grouping another property

Tags: kotlin, objectbox, objectbox-android

Imagine I have this table:

| tagId | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 250 |

And i need to sum the `amount` by grouping the `tagId`.

In SQL we can do this by:
`SELECT tagId, SUM(amount) FROM orders GROUP BY tagId;`

Query result:

| tagId | SUM(amount) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 250 |
| 2 | 450 |

How can I get such results in ObjectBox ?

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no GROUP function in ObjectBox. Instead, write code to process query results in which ever way you desire. There are built-in property queries that can return a sum that may be helpful:

```
val sum = tagBox.query(Tag_.id.equals(id)).build()
    .property(Tag_.amount)
    .sumDouble()
```

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#propertyquery

Comment: Thanks for your help @uwe-objectbox . The problem is i have many Tags and i can't query each of them separately. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not (e.g. use a property query to get all tag IDs with distinct() and findInts())? If performance is an issue I guess using find() and summing up results with your code is probably faster. It's also possible to use find with limit and offset to get results in batches if memory consumption is a concern.